# Difference between Identity Matrix and Identity Tensor

Tags: matrices, tensors

I was thinking whether the identity matrix could be considered as a rank 2 tensor or not, but then I found out that there is a tensor called identity tensor that has the same function.

So what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tensor is an object satisfying a certain transformation law relating its components in different coordinate systems. Any tensor which has the same components as the identity matrix in *one* Cartesian coordinate system also achieves that in *all* others obtainable by an orthogonal transformation. But more general transformations can have different effects. For example, a Euclidean plane satisfies$$\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2=\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2=g_{ab}\mathrm{d}x^a\mathrm{d}x^b.$$In Cartesian coordinates, the metric tensor's components are those of the identity matrix, viz. $g_{ab}=\delta_{ab}$. In polar coordinates, the matrix we get is $\operatorname{diag}(1,\,r^2)$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. So the identity matrix can't be considered as a rank 2 identity tensor. But the rank 2 identity tensor has the same components of identity matrix. Right?

Comment: @Unknown It's precisely because the components vary under general coordinate transformations that we can't talk of an "identity tensor", unless it's a mixed tensor viz. $g_{ab}g^{bc}=\delta_a^c$, but even then we'd usually call it the Kronecker delta. The correct name for the tensor denoted $g_{ab}$ is the (index-lowering) *metric tensor*. In a non-Euclidean manifold, its components won't be those of an identity matrix even in Cartesian coordinates, because its eigenvalues will be of mixed sign.